# Error when trying to use RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter, refresh, page-refresh

I am trying to integrate the RefreshIndicator in my view but when I do the pull down I get an error and it doesn't tell me which one it is

This is my code:

```
class CourseListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CourseListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var courses = context.select((CourseProvider provider) => provider.courses);

    return Expanded(
      child: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          courses =
              context.select((CourseProvider provider) => provider.courses);
        },
        child: (courses == null)
            ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : (courses.isEmpty)
                ? const Center(child: Text('No hay cursos publicados.'))
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: courses.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final course = courses?.elementAt(index);
                      return CourseCard(course!);
                    },
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what it shows me when I do the pull down and it freezes:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyFzJ.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, Please try with below codes.**

```
class CourseListView extends StatelessWidget {
const CourseListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var courses = context.select((CourseProvider provider) => 
 provider.courses);

return Expanded(
  child: (courses == null)
      ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      : (courses.isEmpty)
          ? const Center(child: Text('No hay cursos publicados.'))
          : RefreshIndicator(
              triggerMode: RefreshIndicatorTriggerMode.onEdge,
              onRefresh: () async {
                courses = context.select((CourseProvider provider) => provider.courses);
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: courses.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final course = courses?.elementAt(index);
                  return CourseCard(course!);
                },
              ),
            ),
  );
 }
}
```